# convert C# project on Windows 7 64 bit machine to Windows xp 32 bit?

Tags: c#, sql-server, crystal-reports-2010

How can I convert a C# project on a Windows 7 64-bit machine to run on Windows xp 32-bit?

Comment: What exactly leads you to believe that a conversion is necessary? Are you getting an error when you try to run on XP?

Answer (score 3):

On project set Platform target to x86.

Answer (score 3):

You can also set the Platform target to AnyCPU, then the project will run on both machines natively. There is a good explanation of how to do this in this post: [How to add x64 (or Any CPU) as a build option in Visual Studio 2010 (from console application to class library)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8333468/how-to-add-x64-or-any-cpu-as-a-build-option-in-visual-studio-2010-from-consol)