# MS Visual Studio Professional 2013 - C++ Compile single executable for 32bit and 64bit operating systems?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, 32bit-64bit, configurationmanager

Google gave me a clue that *it is possible* to compile code into a single executable that will run as **32bit on a 32bit OS** and as **64bit on a 64bit OS**. Is it really possible for the executable to determine its bitness at runtime?

In my case the target systems would be `Windows 7 Professional x64` and `Windows XP SP3 x86`.

So what I read on various articles (I think there was even answers to similiar topics on SO) is that one has to go to the `Soltuion`'s `Configuration Manager` (**RMB onto Solution** -> **Configuration Manager**) and set the `Platform` to **Any CPU**.

Now all of these articles described a setup for older MSVS or MSVC++ versions, but I think there are no major changes to the `Configuration Manager` in the 2013 RC version (which I have just recently installed).

In the `Active Solution` dropdown I do not have the option `Any CPU`, so I followed **[this recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8334331/1686067)** that I found on SO. Following this little guide fails in my case, I still do not have the option to select `Any CPU` when following step 5:

- 5) Make sure "Any CPU" is selected under New Platform. If there was
  no Any CPU solution platform in step 3, then make sure the "Create
  new solutions platform" checkbox is checked. Then click OK.

The dropdown items that are available to me are `x64` and `ARM` (`Win32` too but that is already added by default), I **can not** chose `Any CPU`.

Adding target platform `x64` and compiling the executable works fine, the program is ran as 64bit on Windows 7 x64 but ofcourse it can not be run on the 32bit Windows XP machine.

How do I set the target platform to `Any CPU` in **Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2013 RC**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is absolutely not. You need to define separate executables.

The "Any CPU" dropdown is there to allow you to set compiler settings for more than one platform (e.g. a _DEBUG processor for x64 and Win32) You cannot actually build to that target.

Comment: The "Any CPU" setting applies to pure MSIL output and not native C++ compilations.

Answer (score 2):

AnyCPU refers to .Net programs, not C++. C++ must compile down to native, either x86 or x64. You could build 64 bit program and bundle it into your 32 program, extracting it at runtime. This technique is used by [ProcessExplorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps not a true answer, but for MOST things, running 32-bit code on a 64-bit system works absolutely fine. Of course, it may run a little slower, but compared to having to deal with (and thoroughly test) two different binaries, unless it's significant performance benefits in 64-bit mode (or your application uses more than around 2GB of memory space), I'd be very tempted to use 32-bit mode.

Comment: Same answer I was going to give.  It is worth pointing out, however, that the WOW64 layer needed to run 32-bit executables is not present in the Windows Preinstallation Environment, or some server configurations (Server Core perhaps?)

Comment: [It is indeed Server Core](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371790.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

MacOS supports something called "fat binaries", where the program is compiled twice and both versions are packed into a single file. The OS decides which version to actually launch.

Windows doesn't have anything like it.

Answer (score 1):

You can compile the .NET wrapper (Any CPU) and the rest of program as yourprogram86.dll and yourprogram64.dll

```
[DllImport("yourprogram32.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "open")]
public static extern void open32();

[DllImport("yourprogram64.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "open")]
public static extern void open64();       

static bool Is64()
{
    //.Net 4.0
    //Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem

    //.Net 2.0
    return IntPtr.Size == 8;
}

static void open()
{
  if (Is64())
    open64();
  else
    open32();
}
```