# How to change Plattform in Visual C# 2010

Tags: visual-c#-express-2010

if I create a new project in visual c# 2010 express there is selected "Any CPU".

Because I've a external dll that's compiled as amd64, I've to change the plattform from "Any CPU" to "x64" ... but the field is gray

How can I do that?

Btw. Yes, ist's a x64 computer and win 7.

Thank you in advance,
craCH

Answer (score 0):

Do you have admin access on the machine? If yes, try to vs2010 as admin then change the platform cpu. See if this works!

Comment: Yes, I've admin-access and no I cant change anything.

Comment: Yes, as written ... the fields are gray

Comment: Did you click on the windows start button, right click on vs2010 and select "run as adminstrator" ?

Comment: Hello, i saw this link today. Please check if you will get any useful information. Thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4104228/change-target-cpu-settings-in-visual-studio-2010-express  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8333468/how-to-add-x64-or-any-cpu-as-a-build-option-in-visual-studio-2010-from-consol

Comment: Thats it ... Options --> Projects and Solutions --> General --> Show advanced build configurations ... many thanks